# Creating domain expertise features as feature-engineering methods

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, feature-engineering

can you explain to me what is the method of (**Creating domain expertise features)**? I have already read a paper that they mentioned this as as method of feature engineering. this is the link of paper:
https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=7937700&casa_token=4-z8UtRkp1UAAAAA:nsm1HOViwJA6W0lsQz-vTN05OV308R1VvO0c0sjhoAnsspR0ryqrjwApjG0ayUT7IdY4WU1E&tag=1

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The paper you linked to is not accessible (only the intro), but this seems like some prior knowledge was used to build the features. These are sometimes called *expert knowledge features.*

For example, say I want to predict apple pie taste score and I know that in the apple pie\desserts domain people that score the taste like sugar - I would use this knowledge to have features about the sugar levels.